# Convert the following array data as Json in react

Tags: reactjs

I need to convert the following array data to Json in react.
I tried map method, but it is not the correct way. I need key value pair, so that i can pass it to server as json

```
 [
                   [
                      "channel",
                      "s1"
                   ],
                   [
                      "category",
                      "Account 1"
                   ],
                   [
                      "accountAdministration",
                      "Partnership 1"
                   ],
                   [
                      "partnershipAccounting",
                      "1 level Performance issues"
                   ],
                   [
                      "requestCategory",
                      "Research"
                   ],
                   [
                      "severity",
                      "Blocker"
                   ],
                   [
                      "activationDate",
                      "2020-10-29T05:54:00.000Z"
                   ],
                   [
                      "managerApproved",
                      true
                   ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `reduce` and creating an object:

```
var arr = []; // your array

var data = arr.reduce((map, item) => {
  map[item[0]] = item[1];
  return map;
}, {});
```

The `data` object will be in the following format:

```
{
  "accountAdministration": "Partnership 1",
  "activationDate": "2020-10-29T05:54:00.000Z",
  "category": "Account 1",
  "channel": "s1",
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked with

Object.fromEntries([
[
"channel",
"s1"
],
[
"category",
"Account 1"
],
[
"accountAdministration",
"Partnership 1"
],
[
"partnershipAccounting",
"1 level Performance issues"
],
[
"requestCategory",
"Research"
],
[
"severity",
"Blocker"
],
[
"activationDate",
"2020-10-29T05:54:00.000Z"
],
[
"managerApproved",
true
]
])